# Scanning in characters and then using them in IF statements? (if char=='c') {} etc

Tags: c

My code thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() 
{
    float p_Asphalt = 5.2, p_Concrete = 4.93, p_Stones = 2.21;
    float c_Concrete = 8.88; 
    float d_Length =, d_Width;
    char typeOfPaving, c_Curbing;
    float totalCost = 0;
    float GST = 1.13, PST = 1.10;

    printf("asphalt company\n\n");
    printf("Length of Driveway: ");
        scanf("%f", &d_Length);
    printf("Width of Driveway: ");
        scanf("%f", &d_Width);
    printf("\nType of Paving:\n");
    printf(" 'A' for asphalt paving\n");
    printf(" 'C' for concrete paving\n");
    printf(" 'S' for paving stones\n\n");
    printf("Select (A,C,S): ");
        scanf("%c%c", &typeOfPaving);
    printf("%c", typeOfPaving);

    if (typeOfPaving == "A") 
    {
        totalCost = p_Asphalt * (d_Length * d_Width);
        printf("Concrete curbing? [y/n]: ");

            scanf("%c%c", c_Curbing);

            if (c_Curbing == 'y') { 
                totalCost = totalCost + (d_Length * c_Concrete);
            }
            else {
                totalCost = totalCost * GST;
                printf("Quoted Price of Paving: %f\n", totalCost);
            }
    } 
    else if (typeOfPaving == "C") 
    {
        totalCost = p_Concrete * (d_Length * d_Width);
        printf("Quoted Price of Paving: %f\n", totalCost);
    } 
    else if (typeOfPaving == "S") 
    {
        totalCost = p_Stones * (d_Length * d_Width);
        printf("Quoted Price of Paving: %f\n", totalCost);
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I compile, I get the following output:

```
:~/> cc assignment1.c ^C
:~/>
:~/> a.out
asphalt company

Length of Driveway: 123
Width of Driveway: 123

Type of Paving:
 'A' for asphalt paving
 'C' for concrete paving
 'S' for paving stones

Select (A,C,S): A

:~/>
```

Nothing happens. On line 22 where I have `scanf("%c%c", &typeOfPaving);`, I use %c%c because my professor told me that the first %c stores the new line character after inputting data into the variable d_Width on line 16: `scanf("%f", &d_Width);`. Problem I see now is that (I think?) that char typeOfPaving stores \nA? not just A so my if statements won't work? Is that correct?

Can somebody please help me, not sure what to do lol, kind of frustrating

Comment: Since this is homework, I'll be vague on purpose, but double-quotes indicate strings of characters in C, and single quotes indicate single characters.  You aren't dealing with strings, but you compared against one.

Comment: Your professor is misguiding you: if you have 2 conversion specifiers in the `scanf` you should have 2 address in the following arguments.

Comment: @pmg I was also about to say so, but... OP was just told to use %c%c to skip \n which would be ok if he also specified two args later. Btw C Prog Lang (2nd) on scanf says on 'c' formatter: as it does not skip white char to read next non white char use %1s.

Comment: Use a space to ignore whitespace: `scanf(" ");`, or `scanf(" %c", whatever);` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done well by forming a hypothesis that explains why your program is misbehaving. The next important step is figuring out a test that will confirm or refute the hypothesis. That is, if you are claiming that `typeOfPaving` stores `\nA`, how can you test if this is the case?

If it is the case, what can you do to correct the problem? If it is not the case, what is your next hypothesis?

You'll find that practising this will lead you further than seeking an exact answer from someone.

Answer (score 2):

`"C"` is a `char` array, `'C'` is a `char`. That's what you probably need:

```
if (typeOfPaving == 'C')
```

Comment: Damnit. Funny story actually. The version I posted up there was just an experiment with double quotes. I was actually using single quotes the whole time and it still didn't work lol. So that voids a majority of responses here.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I've seen is a comparison `typeOfPaving == "A"`, that is a character and an array of characters, which is wrong.

*Doesn't your compiler ever warn you?*

Also, when you pass variables to `scanf` you should *always* pass pointers, not just sometimes. (unless your variable is a pointer, of course).

And you should pass as many pointers as `%`-placeholders you have, otherwise things will go wrong.

Comment: In C `"A"` is not of type `const char*`, it is of type `char[2]` (and usually decays to a value of type `char*`).

Comment: @pmg actually isn't it `char const[2]`?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: my first comment is accurate. The type of string literals is an array of `N` elements (with `N` just large enough for all the characters and a NUL terminator). See 6.4.5 in [the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.4.5).

Comment: @pmg it does say _The same considerations apply to each element of the sequence in a character string literal or a wide string literal as if it were in an integer character **constant** or a wide character **constant** _ and also _ If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined_. Although that does not specify whether the actual type of the array is `const` or not, it pretty much says that it has to act like it is, if I didn't misread. Perhaps this is one of the differences between C and C++, because in C++ it definitely is explicitly a `char const[]`

Comment: One implementation does not necessarily confirm the rules, but [ideone](http://ideone.com/hVysb) follows the standard. If you notice lines 18 and 20 try to pass `const` data to the function and fail; while line 16 (with the string literal) works.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
scanf("%c%c", c_Curbing);
```

is very wrong, and should give you a compiler error (or at least a warning). The `scanf()` function needs a pointer, so  you must use:

```
scanf("%c", &c_Curbing);
```

Also, it's strange to supply more formatting specifiers than pointers to variables to recieve the values.

Lastly, you really should check the *return value* to make sure that it succeeded in reading the expected data.

Comment: He explained why he had two `%c`s in the question.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, yes, but still both placeholders need to have corresponding pointers.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker yes, my comment was directed at "it's strange to supply more formatting specifiers than pointers to variables..." I was just saying that he had a reason for doing that, even though it didn't do what he thought it did

Comment: But his professor could at least have instructed him to assign it to a dummy. The way it is now, it is is a chainsaw waiting to happen.

Comment: I just put a space like this ` %c` and it worked magically. Don't know why. I need somebody to explain this to me, I have no idea why it's working but I want to learn.